# Doing 2 Left Joins on the same table with one call

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following tables:

**Users:**

- `userId`, `userFirstName`, `userLastName`.

**holdBilling:**

- `bEntityID`, `CarrierOID`, `PayerOID`, `holdTYPE`, `createUserID`.

**carrier:**

- `carrierOID`, `carrierName`.

**payer:**

- `payerOID`, `payerName`.

I want the code to save in a new entity

```
holdBilling => new
{
      FirstName, LastName, CarrierName, PayerName
}
```

One of these Entities has either a payer or a carrier value (cannot have both). Basically i want to make 2 left joins on the same table with one call. This would be the SQL query that would work for me.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[bEntityID]
      ,c.carrierID
      ,c.carrierName
      ,p.payerID
      ,p.payerName
      ,[holdType] ( this is "C" for carrier and "P" for payer ) 
  FROM .[dbo].[holdBilling] hb
  left join dbo.payer p on hb.payerID = p.payerID
  left join dbo.carrier c on hb.carrierID = c.carrierID
  where [bEntityID] = 378
```

The temporary solution I've found is getting a list of all Carriers

```
 var listC = (from hold in holdBilling
              join u in Users on hold.createUserID equals u.userID
              join c in carrier.DefaultIfEmpty() on hold.carrierID equals c.carrierID
                             select new
                             {
                                 Elem = hold,
                                 FName = u.userFirstName,
                                 LName = u.userLastName,
                                 Carrier = c.carrierName,
                                 Payer = ""
                             }).ToList();
```

and one for all payers

```
 select new
        {
            Elem = hold,
            FName = u.userFirstName,
            LName = u.userLastName,
            Carrier = "",
            Payer = p.payerName
        }).ToList();
```

and merging the two,I'm confident there has to be a solution for doing both in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
var listC = (
                from hb in holdBilling
                from p in payer.Where(a=>a.payerID==hb.payerID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from c in carrier.Where(a=>a.carrierID=hb.carrierID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                where hb.bEntityID==378
                select new
                {
                    hb.bEntityID,
                    c.carrierID,
                    c.carrierName,
                    p.payerID,
                    p.payerName,
                    holdType=(payer==null?"P":"C")
                }
                ).Take(1000)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Although all the answers helped, this was the one that was closest to the actual solution : one small improvement thou: (c != null) ?c.carrierName : "" was needed; not just for the c.carrierName field. Thanks for the fast answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356814.aspx) to do a left join

```
 var listC = (from hold in holdBilling
              from u in Users.Where(x => hold.createUserID == x.userID).DefaultIfEmpty()
              from c in carrier.Where(x => hold.carrierID == x.carrierID).DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                Elem = hold,
                FName = u.userFirstName,
                LName = u.userLastName,
                Carrier = c.carrierName,
                Payer = ""
              }).ToList();
```